# How to use extensions to simplify Swift code?

Tags: ios, swift, extension-methods

Say I have many functions that return more than one `UIColor`. Let's take a look at one of them:

```
func deepSkyBlue() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.69, blue: 0.98, alpha: 1)
}
```

All my functions have `alpha` equal to 1.0, so it'd make sense to use an extension and omit one argument entirely. How can I do this?

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Comment: `Missing argument for parameter 'alpha' in call`. In fact, I still have to find a way to implement the `neverAlpha` code into my `UIColor` functions. Thanks!

Comment: So the compiler error is not for `neverAlpha`, but is for `deepSkyBlue`?

Comment: I've posted an answer for you, so perhaps stop editing your question for a second and see if that works for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we want our `alpha` to be assumed as 1.0 when we don't pass it to the `UIColor` constructor, all we need to do is add a new constructor in an extension.

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

And now we can use the three argument constructor you tried using:

```
static func deepSkyBlue() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.69, blue: 0.98)
}
```